# How can I scale an embedded video?

Tags: video, iframe, responsive-design

I have a column of images with a class of "scale-with-grid" that resize fine when reducing the screen size. However, when applying this class to an embedded video it doesn't work. I've done something similar before which worked out okay... could anyone please point me in the right direction?

My site is here http://v3.edharrisondesign.com/project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or. You can use a really good lightweight jQuery plugin called fitvidsjs
Here is the link http://fitvidsjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I wasn't properly thinking - easy solution. Just gave the video a different class and gave it a specific height and width at each screen size in the media queries.